# MassTransit publish to AWS topics from different accounts

Tags: masstransit

I'm evaluating implementing MassTransit in replacement of native AWS SDK but I'm wondering if it supports configuring cross-account Topics.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

- Topic **TopicA** exists in account **1111** (arn:aws:sns::1111:TopicA).
- Topic **TopicB** exists in account **2222** (arn:aws:sns::2222:TopicB).
- Application **AppA**, deployed in account **1111**, needs to publish both **TopicA** and **TopicB**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, that isn't supported since MassTransit doesn't allow you to specify the ARN for a topic or queue, only the name.